# Analytic function not yielding result for multiple object collection outputs in pl/sql

Tags: sql, collections, oracle11g, window-functions

I have a global collection type of varchar2(100) defined in oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE final_score_typ AS TABLE OF varchar2(1000);
```

Values in the collection:

> 'KI~296~1~9','US~CA~2~11','CA~CA~2~11','KP~KOREA~2~14','KR~KOREA~2~14','US~CA~3~19','CA~CA~3~24'

scenario 1 (only one element could have the highest based on below logic):

I have to get the element within the collection that satisfies the following rule:
I have to look at the value in the 3rd subelement with each of these elements and pick the one that has the highest value. 
In the above data, the 3rd subelements are 1,2,2,2,2,3,3 (immediately following the second ~). Obviously here, the elements containing 3 are higher. So, 2 of them meet the criteria. 
Further, from the 2 of them, I have to look at the 4th subelement and ultimately pick the one that has the highest value. So, the 4th subelement for these 2 are: 19 and 24. 
Since 24 is the highest in this case, the final output is to pick the element CA~CA~3~24.

This query (given by an expert in this forum a while back) works:

```
select min(column_value) keep (dense_rank first order by 
   to_number(regexp_substr(column_value, '[^~]+', 1, 3)) desc nulls last, 
   to_number(regexp_substr(column_value, '[^~]+', 1, 4)) desc nulls last
   ) from table(final_score_typ('KI~296~1~9','US~CA~2~11','CA~CA~2~11','KP~KOREA~2~14','KR~KOREA~2~14','US~CA~3~19','CA~CA~3~24'));
```

Scenario 2 (multiple elements could have a tie based on below logic): Rules are the same

If the collection has data such that it could produce a tie, then the above query does not work and I am not sure how to get all those tie data back as a result.
values:

> final_score_typ('KI~296~1~9','US~CA~2~11','CA~CA~2~11','KP~KOREA~2~14','KR~KOREA~2~14','US~CA~3~19','CA~CA~3~19')

Here, both 'US~CA~3~19' and 'CA~CA~3~19' are valid as their 3rd subelement is highest and their 4th is the same value of 19.
Here, my output should be to return them both.
Currently, the above query picks 'CA~CA~3~19' based on the min logic.

Comment: Can you change your storage and use a regular table instead?  Or at least an object type with a column for each value?

Comment: I think it should not matter as the advantage of the object type is to use it in sql as a table. I can still separate the sub-elements within them. So, they are as good as separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining analytic functions with inline views can help break a complicated process into simple steps.  The only tricky part is the logic flows from the middle to the outside, which is different than typical procedural program.

```
--#3: Top values
select column_value
from
(
    --#2: Ranked values
    select col1, col2, col3, col4, column_value
        ,rank() over (order by col3 desc, col4 desc) my_rank
    from
    (
        --#1: Collection split into columns
        select
            regexp_substr(column_value, '[^~]+', 1, 1) col1
            ,regexp_substr(column_value, '[^~]+', 1, 2) col2
            ,to_number(regexp_substr(column_value, '[^~]+', 1, 3)) col3
            ,to_number(regexp_substr(column_value, '[^~]+', 1, 4)) col4
            ,column_value
        --from table(final_score_typ('KI~296~1~9','US~CA~2~11','CA~CA~2~11',
        --  'KP~KOREA~2~14','KR~KOREA~2~14','US~CA~3~19','CA~CA~3~24'))
        from table(final_score_typ('KI~296~1~9','US~CA~2~11','CA~CA~2~11',
            'KP~KOREA~2~14','KR~KOREA~2~14','US~CA~3~19','CA~CA~3~19'))
    ) collection_split_into_columns
) ranked_values
where my_rank = 1;
```

Comment: excellent...thanks...looks alright. But, i will just have to validate it further for the upvote. But, nice !